# NodeJs: Express app don't start in windows

Tags: node.js, express

I'm just starting with node.js and express framework, following this tutorial:

http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html

After running in console `express myapp` and `cd myapp && npm install` when I run `node app.js` nothing happens. The command returns immediately, while I was expecting it to wait for incoming messages. No error are shown either. I'm on Windows 7 x64 and the commands are run from an ADMIN console.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial says to run

```
set DEBUG=myapp & node ./bin/www
```

You don't run it with

```
node app.js
```

in express v4.x

Comment: Thanks, but when I paste "DEBUG=myapp ./bin/www" in my windows console it throws an error: 

'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: are you using cmd or powershell?

Comment: cmd. Shuld I switch to PS?

Comment: Similar erro in PS:

PS D:\temp\node\myapp> DEBUG=myapp ./bin/www
The term 'DEBUG=myapp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
 spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:12
+ DEBUG=myapp <<<<  ./bin/www
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DEBUG=myapp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: No that's fine. In CMD to set an environment variable I think you have to type `set DEBUG=myapp` then you can run `./bin/www`

Comment: I doubt it.. "./bin/www" is not a valid path to an executable under win

Comment: I opened up a ticket on the website: https://github.com/strongloop/expressjs.com/issues/243 and now that you've set the environment variable using `set` try running `./bin/www` with `node .\bin\www`

Comment: The following command worked: "set DEBUG=myapp&node ./bin/www" Thanks for your help!

Comment: The [pull request](https://github.com/strongloop/expressjs.com/issues/243) was accepted and the instructions will include Windows instructions on next deploy

Comment: & operator is not allowed in PS. Any equivalent command for PS?

Answer (score 3):

after you cd myapp && npm install 
try

```
npm start
```

Comment: `npm ERR! missing script: start`

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 and for other people reading this in the future, I would check my `package.json` and make sure that I have `start` under scripts. Mine says `"start": "node ./bin/www"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing  commands from  'Node.js command prompt' or ' C:\Program Files\Nodejs'.

If it says 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command'

Try adding C:\Program Files\Nodejs to your PATH environment variable.

On the command prompt, the command would be set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Nodejs.

Comment: My problem is not related to node.js path, but node returning immediately without errors when it was supposed to keep alive waiting for connections.

Answer (score 0):

Before you execute

```
express myapp
```

you have to execute

```
npm install express-generator -g
```