# Node.JS Express App Will Not Run on AWS EC2 Instance Running Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, express

I have tried over the past 24 hours to get my express app to run. I've followed tutorials, uninstalled then reinstalled everything and still...no dice.

Here is the [M.E.A.N stack install wiki link](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_MEAN_Stack_(MongoDB%2C_Express%2C_Angular%2C_Node.js)?highlight=MEAN#How_to_start_with_a_sample_MEAN_project.3f) to the setup what I am trying to install.

Here is the code from my command prompt of what happens when I try to run the app

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-43-127:~/projects/sample$ ls
app.js  bin  node_modules  package.json  public  routes  views
bitnami@ip-172-31-43-127:~/projects/sample$ ./bin/www
nothing happens... it will just blink on this line forever♥
bitnami@ip-172-31-43-127:~/projects/sample$ DEBUG=new ./bin/www
same thing. it will blink forever an ⌂d ⌂♥
bitnami@ip-172-31-43-127:~/projects/sample$ DEBUG=new npm start
> sample@0.0.0 start /home/bitnami/projects/sample
> node ./bin/www
slightly different result... but the app is not running on localhost:3000♥
bitnami@ip-172-31-43-127:~/projects/sample$
```

I have tried implementing this from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380025/nodejs-express-app-dont-start-in-windows) and it did not fix

Can someone tell me what I did wrong and how to correct this issue? Thank you! :)

Content of app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
var port = 3000;
app.listen(port, function() {
   console.log('Listening...');
});
```

Comment: Please post text, not images-thanks :)

Comment: How would you expect us to know how to help you if you don't show us your code?

Comment: @jfriend00 I've posted the contents of app.js. My apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running just plain old

```
npm start
```

You can also type `rm -rf bin/` to remove the folder then at the bottom of `app.js` add

```
app.listen(port, function() {
   console.log('Listening...');
});
```

Then run

```
node app
```

Comment: I tried implementing your solution. I get "listening..." in the console now but the app does not render a web page on my localhost:3000

Comment: @MarkusProctor try removing module.exports = app; and do you have the appropriate files in your views for the routes that you have, try going to /hdjdjdj or some random to see if you get an error 404, if you do then it is working properly and you just need to fix your routes or views

Comment: implemented and no dice. Chrome shows "This webpage is not available. Error_Connection_Refused". I installed the package directly from the provider and did not change anything. My EC2 is running on linux if that changes anything.

Comment: @MarkusProctor ok that sounds like a port issue, make sure you have port 3000 open on your ec2 instance. Google how to do that then let me know if it works

Comment: here is the url of my instance http://ec2-52-7-174-251.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ but running the app is not changing the page content at all. I guess the localhost:3000 thing makes sense oops :)

Comment: Make sure the port is open and try to connect to http://ec2-52-7-174-251.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000